# Geometry involving circumcenters

Tags: geometry

In an acute-angled triangle $ABC$, a point $D$ lies on the segment $BC$. Let $O_1$,$O_2$ denote the circumcentres of triangles $ABD$ and $ACD$, respectively. Prove that the line joining the circumcentre of triangle $ABC$ and the orthocentre of triangle $O_1O_2D$ is parallel to $BC$.

Supposing that the circumcentre of $\Delta$$ABC$ is $O$, and the orthocenter of $\Delta$$O_1O_2D$ is H, I could prove that $A,O_1,O,H,O_2$ lie on a circle. After that I cannot figure out how to do. Please help.

[Any other better solution is also welcome :)]

Comment: Please add a diagram.

Comment: Well, the original question did not provide a diagram, the reader had to draw the diagram himself/ herself because there may be variations.

Comment: This is not a site like Brilliant or AOPS. Here, the questioner **must** show effort and then the answer is to help him/her to complete the solution. One has to draw a diagram to solve the problem. Hence, the question is easier to comprehend with a diagram. As for the fact that multiple configurations are possible, draw any possible configuration.

Comment: I do understand, @Anubhab Ghosal. I am not simply posting questions or asking doubts. I do write whatever I have done as a part of my attempt to solve the problem. But please see, I registered with this website just yesterday and I am yet to explore and learn more on this website. So maybe in my future posts I will try my best to post a figure, along with the question, too. Anyways, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You are welcome. Welcome to Math.SE. Enjoy! (I am not sure if I am the right person to welcome you as I myself joined only a month back. :P).

Comment: Haha, thanks for the invitation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proceded starting from your suggestions and then by the following path.
You can use your result to state that 
\begin{equation}
\angle O_2OH \cong\angle O_2AH \cong \angle O_2DH,\tag{1}\label{eq:cong1}
\end{equation} 
where the first congruence is due to the fact that the angles are subtended by the same chord $O_2H$, and the second congruence is due to the fact that triangle $AO_2D$ is isosceles. Call then $M_1$ the middle point of $BC$ and $M_2$ the middle point of $AC$.  Note that
\begin{equation}
\angle O_2OM_1 + \angle ACB \cong \pi,\tag{2}\label{eq:sum1}
\end{equation}
which can be obtained by adding up the internal angles of quadrilateral $CM_2OM_1$. Now subtract and add $\angle O_2OH$ on the LHS of \eqref{eq:sum1}, getting
\begin{eqnarray}
\angle O_2OM_1 -\angle O_2OH+ \angle ACB + \angle O_2OH&\cong& \pi\\
\angle HOM_1 + \angle ACB + \angle O_2OH \cong \pi.
\end{eqnarray}
Finally, by using \eqref{eq:cong1} and properties of the circumcenter $O_2$, show that 
\begin{equation}
\angle ACB + \angle O_2OH \cong \frac{\pi}{2},
\end{equation}
which will lead to the thesis.